# python ttp parser ignore line if I have ORPHRASE in template and consecutive blank spaces in input text

Tags: python, json, parsing

**Envorionment**: windows 10, python: 3.9, ttp: 0.8.4

I'm having a problem with **ORPHRASE** in the TTP template, and if there's consecutive blank-space characters in the string the template is supposed to pick up.

Input text:

```
    vprn 5000122 customer 99999 create
        description "LastMod: Jan 28, 2022 2:33:11 AM"
        vrf-import "VPRN-5000122-IMPORT"
        vrf-export "VPRN-5000122-EXPORT"
        router-id 95.95.95.95
        autonomous-system 5555
        route-distinguisher 4444:8888888
        auto-bind-tunnel
            resolution-filter
                ldp
            exit
            resolution filter
        exit
        interface "*dummy-1* L3 interface"  create
            description "*** single blank-space description ***"
            address 199.199.199.199/32
        exit
        interface "*dummy-2* L3 interface"  create
            description "***  double blank-space description ***"
            address 201.201.201.201/32
        exit
        service-name "dumy-vprn-service"
        no shutdown
    exit
```

TTP template:

```
<group name="service">
<group name="vprn.{{ service_id }}**">
    vprn {{service_id | _start_ }} customer {{customer_id}} create
        description "{{ description | ORPHRASE | default("")}}"
        vrf-import "{{ vrf_import }}"
        vrf-export "{{ vrf_export }}"
        autonomous-system {{ autonous_system }}
        route-distinguisher {{ route_distinguisher }}
    <group name="interface.{{interface_id}}**">
        interface "{{ interface_id | ORPHRASE | _start_ }}" create
            description "{{ description | ORPHRASE }}"
            address {{ ipv4_address }}
            ip-mtu {{ ip_mtu }}
        exit {{ _end_ }}
    </group>
        service-name "{{ service_name }}"
        no shutdown {{ state | set("enabled") | default("disabled") }}
    exit {{ _end_ }}
</group>
```

parsed output:

```
{
"5000122": {
    "route_distinguisher": "4444:8888888",
    "autonous_system": "5555",
    "vrf_export": "VPRN-5000122-EXPORT",
    "vrf_import": "VPRN-5000122-IMPORT",
    "description": "LastMod: Jan 28, 2022 2:33:11 AM",
    "customer_id": "99999",
    "state": "enabled",
    "interface": {
        "*dummy-1* L3 interface": {
            "ipv4_address": "199.199.199.199/32",
            "description": "*** single blank-space description ***"
        },
        "*dummy-2* L3 interface": {
            "ipv4_address": "201.201.201.201/32"
        }
    },
    "service_name": "dumy-vprn-service"
}
```

}

**Problem**:
The description line in the second interface is not picked up by the parser, because the consecutive blank-space characters in the string

Answer (score 0):

you can use *line* instead of ORPHRASE (line with underscore both at the start and end)